# Avoid querying database for each visitor to page in asp.net website

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql

I'm very new to coding websites so please go easy if my terminology is incorrect....

I'm building a website that is accessible to many users. I have a hidden page `GetData.aspx` that I will call via a scheduled task every few hours that will create new data in a SQL database table named `webData`.

When a user navigates to a page, say `ShowData.aspx`, it will present a table (eg gridview control) containing data from the SQL table `webData`.

At the moment, `ShowData.aspx` has C# codebehind on the `Page_Load` event to query data from `webData` and bind the result to a table in the page.

However, both `ShowData.aspx` and `webData` is the same data for **every** single visitor based on the current data in the table. It seems a bit pointless querying a database multiple times for each visitor for the same page output.

Is there a better way of doing this in `asp.net` so a page can be 'pre-rendered' so that it can display the same html+css+gridview+controls to all visitors based on the current data in the SQL table?

Comment: You should Google "caching in ASP.NET". There are multiple levels/types of caching you can do. You can cache the database calls in your memory, you can cache the responses to your clients etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ASP.Net caching. There are different levels of caching.

[ASP.NET Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[ASP.NET Caching: Techniques and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx)

If a user needs to view new content as soon as data is changed in database, you want to use **Cache Object**.